# How to avoid having to `export LC_ALL="zh_CN.UTF-8"` upon each SSH connection

Tags: fedora, locale

Each time I SSH to my Fedora Server, the locale setting is not right.

```
$ locale

locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: ??? LC_ALL ????????: ?????????
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

And each time I would have to `$ export LC_ALL="zh_CN.UTF-8"` to make the desired language work.

But I have already set `LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8` and `LC_ALL=zh_CN.UTF-8` in `/etc/locale.conf/` and in `~/.bashrc`.

Is there any way I can make the `export` permanent? Really appreciate a lot!!

Comment: Are you sshing from a macOS machine? It's the second time I see a LC_CTYPE=UTF-8 today, and the last one was on macOS. Possibly, that's transmitted over ssh. `(unset -v LC_CTYPE; ssh fedora-server)`. Or you could remove the `AcceptEnv LC_*` from your sshd configuration to avoid clients polluting your environment.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yes, exactly. I’m sshing from *High Sierra*. Is it correct to say that the Mac Terminal is sending `LC_CTYPE` to the remote host? But why would it send `UTF-8` without language and region? That’s so odd...

Comment: It seems that's what macOS sets LC_CTYPE to. I suppose it doesn't have a notion of different region-based CTYPEs (CTYPE is not only about the character set) and wants to force the character-set to be UTF-8 regardless of the locale the user selects(?). You'd have to ask apple about the reasoning I suppose, that seems to make little sense to me.

Comment: In any case, I would avoid setting LC_ALL. It would be better to unset LC_CTYPE here. Something like `case $LC_CTYPE in (UTF-8) unset -v LC_CTYPE;; # remove buggy LC_CTYPE sent by macOS` as a work around.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas really appreciate your explanation! I also prefer not to use `LC_ALL`, and the reason why I added that was because it was said to be able to reset all `locale` settings at once. What I actually needed was only `LC_MESSAGES` for the prompts to be translated. Meanwhile, I should clarify that I was not doing all the `locale` settings because Chinese was more readable for me, I was doing that for learning how the locale settings worked. And I surely learned a lot along the way. XD Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the `export` in your `~/.bashrc`.

```
export LC_ALL=zh_CN.UTF-8
```

When you login to your user in the remote server via `ssh`, the `~/.bashrc` of that user will get sourced and the `locale` will be set.

Comment: Thanks! Do I need to do the same in `/etc/locale.conf` as well?

Comment: I do not think so, `~/.bashrc` is sourced and the `locale` is set when you login.

Comment: So, is the setting in `/etc/locale.conf` unnecessary? I am kinda puzzled how the `locale` setting works now...

Answer (score -1):

You should set LC_CTYPE variable to zh_CN.UTF-8

In MAC OS X, Open Terminal.cpp -> preference -> profiles-> Advance -> uncheck "set locale environment variable on startup"
And It's ok.